# SPFx - List out all labels within a Term Set (Term store)

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, term-store, term

Inside a SPFx web part, I have been trying really hard to list out the labels (red, blue, green) within the Favourite term set. I have not yet been able to achieve this.

Does anybody know how to do this? My brain is melting :(

code:

```
  public async componentDidMount() {

    const store: ITermStore = taxonomy.termStores.getByName("Taxonomy_O1cHqzMmDZNz4UeaKJLVpA==");

    // get a single term by id
    const term: ITerm = store.getTermById("6a488843-cebc-47b7-8606-e4e165e6fceb");

    const labels: ILabels = term.labels;

    const labelsWithData = term.labels.get();

    { setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('1', store);
      console.log('2',labels);
      console.log('3',labelsWithData);
    }, 2000); }

  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample test code for your reference.

```
public componentDidMount() {

    var store: ITermStore = taxonomy.termStores.getByName("Taxonomy_hAIlyuIrZSNizRU+uUbanA==");
    var set: ITermSet = store.getTermSetById("70719569-ae34-4f24-81b9-0629d68c05aa");    
    // load the data into the terms instances
    set.terms.get().then((terms:ITerm[])=>{
      terms.forEach((term: ITerm) => {
        console.log(term['Name']);
      })
    });
}
```

[image]

[image]